# Create a Lookup<,> from a IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>>

Tags: c#, linq

I'm not sure this question fits in StackOverflow. If that's the case, please let me know.

I'm trying to create a [`Lookup<,>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-5.0) from an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>>`, just for the sake of it (this isn't an XY problem).
My understanding is that the only way to create a [`Lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-5.0) object is with the [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-5.0) method.
The best way I found to do this is to separate the groupings into key-value pairs with duplicate keys and then group it again into a [`Lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-5.0) using [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-5.0):

```cs
groups // IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>
    .SelectMany(group => group.Select(item => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TElement>(group.Key, item)))
    .ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
```

I think this is very inefficient because it separates the groups and then 'reassembles' them, instead of taking advantage of the fact that they're already grouped.
**Is there a better way to do this?**

---

**Possible use case:**
Let's say we have a list of names. We want to group the names by their first letter, so far so good, but we only want to keep groups with more than two names, and we want the result to be a `Lookup<,>` so we'll have access to its useful [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2.item?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Lookup_2_Item__0_).
The first part can be done easily:

```cs
names.GroupBy(name => name[0]).Where(group => group.Count() > 2)
```

But then we will need to convert the `IEnumerable<IGrouping<char, string>>` to a `Lookup<char, string>`.

---

What reasons there are for not having a constructor equivalent to [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair__0__1___)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the possible reasons that could explain why such functionality is not available that Marc pointed out, I just wanted to add that the indexer is also available in Dictionary, so you could create a `IDictionary<char, IEnumerable<string>>` and then keep in mind that you will get an Exception if you use the indexer with a key that's not in the dictionary (which is an important difference with the indexer in the `ILookup`... in addition to the Lookup being immutable in contrast to the dictionary).

So you could do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var names = new List<string>();
        
        names.Add("Agustin");   
        names.Add("Alejandro"); 
        names.Add("Diego"); 
        names.Add("Damian");
        names.Add("Dario");
        
        IDictionary<char, IEnumerable<string>> fakeLookup = names.GroupBy(name => name[0])
            .Where(group => group.Count() > 2)
            .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.AsEnumerable());
        
        foreach(var name in fakeLookup ['D'])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        var namesStartingWithA = lookup['A']; // This will throw a KeyNotFoundException

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the intention of attaching the `AsEnumerable` operator?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias not really since `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable`, but then I would need to use `var` for declaring `fakeLookup`, and I just wanted to explicitly show the types in this snippet and match the ones used by the OP

Comment: By hiding the identity of the underlying `IGrouping` you may prevent LINQ from optimizing some operations on the groupings, like the `Count()`. The LINQ can take a fast path and skip enumerating the items one by one, if it knows the underlying type. But I am not 100% sure that the `AsEnumerable` hides the identity in a way that disables these optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me why the [`Lookup<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2) class is publicly exposed. This class has no public constructors, and it seems that there is no public API that returns this concrete type. The [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup) LINQ operator returns an interface ([`ILookup<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.ilookup-2)) instead of this type.

If you want to convert efficiently an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>>` to an `ILookup<TKey, TValue>`, without reconstructing the groupings from scratch, there seems to be no other option than writing a custom implementation of this interface. The implementation does not need to be public, and it's quite straightforward:

```
private class LookupOfGroupings<TKey, TValue> : ILookup<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, IGrouping<TKey, TValue>> _dictionary;

    public LookupOfGroupings(IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>> source) =>
        _dictionary = source.ToDictionary(g => g.Key);

    public int Count => _dictionary.Count;

    public IEnumerable<TValue> this[TKey key]
        => _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var g) ? g : Enumerable.Empty<TValue>();

    public bool Contains(TKey key) => _dictionary.ContainsKey(key);

    public IEnumerator<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
        => _dictionary.Values.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

The behavior of the indexer is the same with the behavior of the native implementation. In case of a non-existent key, it returns an empty sequence.

And here is the custom `ToLookup` operator that performs the conversion:

```
public static ILookup<TKey, TValue> ToLookup<TKey, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>> source)
        => new LookupOfGroupings<TKey, TValue>(source);
```

Usage example:

```
ILookup<char, string> lookup = names
    .GroupBy(name => name[0])
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 2)
    .ToLookup();
```

Comment: The useful thing about Lookup is that is has `ApplyResultSelector` ... but in order to reach it you have to cast the resault of `ToLookup` to `Lookup<,>`

Comment: @kofifus true, but the `ApplyResultSelector` is not much different than a direct `Select` projection on the `ILookup<K,V>`. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Lookup.cs#L171), it is only slightly more efficient (less enumerators), and it also trims the groupings to minimize their size in memory.

Comment: It's strange ILookup doesn't have ApplyResultSelector .. the whole thing seems half baked :(

Comment: @kofifus maybe the `Lookup<K,V>` was intended to be `internal`, and slipped during the release of the .NET Framework 3.5. And since backward compatibility is a [religion](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2425867 "Sharp Regrets: Top 10 Worst C# Features") in Microsoft's world, they had to keep it public in next versions. At least that's my theory. :-)

Answer (score 0):

"What reasons there are for not having a constructor equivalent to..." - because **every** feature needs to be:

1. thought of
2. considered
3. designed
4. implemented
5. tested
6. documented
7. supported

and either a) it didn't get to #1, or b) it was thought of, but got thrown out or deferred somewhere between #2 and #7, because either c) it was actively thought to be a bad idea, or d) it was a good-enough idea, but when compared to the *sea* of good ideas, it didn't meet the necessary threshold of benefit vs effort to get given the time to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> The best way I found to do this is to separate the groupings into key-value pairs with duplicate keys and then group it again

If efficiency is the concern, I'm not really sure why you didn't just go straight to a lookup:

```
var look = names.ToLookup(n=> n[0], n => n);
```

Then you can ignore the entries that have less than 3 as you use the lookup.. If you'll be performing it a lot, make a method, local function or class to encapsulate the logic. You also mentioned about memory, but it's somewhat moot unless you get rid of names and just retain the lookup - the lookup doesn't contain a clone of all the names/you're not burning a huge amount extra by indexing these items you won't end up using. If you're after a truly efficient (for speed and memory) solution, don't use LiNQ

Comment: I didn't go straight to a lookup exactly because the "must have two names" part. Remember it's just a possible use case to demonstrate why this would be useful, not the essence of the question.

Comment: But the "two names" bit came later, and if you do a group, then a where, then to a lookup it might just be more efficient to go straight to a lookup and put the "two names" bit into whatever uses the lookup..

Comment: But if I use the lookup many times it would be exhausting to check the number of names in each group every time, and also it'll consume more space.

Comment: These are all completely addressable, resolvable or moot "problems" you're inventing but I get the feeling that if I respond to them, the hairs will be split again.. Don't forget that one of the original laments of the question was inefficiency..

Comment: Unrelated to our conversation, the "must have two names" bit wasn't added in an edit.

Comment: I agree with you, these are all completely addressable, resolvable or moot "problems". But that's just an example of a  use case. I don't need this conversion for anything, I'm only doing this for my curiosity. I *personally* didn't like your workaround (putting the "two names" bit into whatever uses the lookup instead of in the lookup itself), I liked better dglozano's workaroung (using a dictionary instead of a lookup). Thank you for your time.

Comment: The problem is this is an entirely manufactured problem, that is ultimately an XY - you decided you wanted to use a lookup, you found you need to group, count, where, selectmany, lookup, to get around the immutability "problem". Someone then says to use a dictionary which is more what should have been used from the start, though it's not what was asked for, but the proposal is still inefficient. Going straight to a lookupnand ignoring is more efficient, but you don't like it. If you want to eat the efficiency cake and have it too you'll probably have to avoid LINQ, build a dictionary in 1 pass

Comment: then remove non qualifying entries (but that visits every key; if you'll use the lookup less than that it's more efficient to build use and ignore)..

Comment: Why do you think that going straight to `Lookup` and having to check the number of names everywhere you use the `Lookup` is more efficient than grouping (which is similar to creating a `Lookup`), filtering it once, and using a `Dictionary`? It seems to me that the `Dictionary` sulotion would be more efficient since you need to check the number of names of each group only once, compared to the your solution which will have to check the number of names of each group every time the `Lookup` is used. Maybe I'm missing something, I'm assuming that `ToLookup` and `GroupBy` have similar performance.

Comment: One reason to use `GroupBy` instead would be that it has deferred execution? The lookup will be filtering after loading the groups. So that's a big difference that ofc depends on the LINQ provider